# Gnuplot pm3d map: different x2tics, y2tics

Tags: gnuplot

I can plot a "ploe figure" with:

```
degtorad(x)=x/180*pi
radtodeg(x)=x/pi*180

set pm3d map
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
set logscale zcb

set palette model RGB rgbformulae 33,13,10

set size ratio 1

set xtics("{/Symbol b}=180{/Symbol \260}" 0)

set ytics("0" -90, "10" -80, "20" -70, "30" -60, "40" -50, "50" -40, "60" -30, "70" -20, "80" -10, "90" 0, "80" 10, "70" 20, "60" 30, "50" 40, "40" 50, "30" 60, "20" 70, "10" 80, "0" 90)

splot[-90:90][-90:90] 'TSC3.txt' u (radtodeg(cos(degtorad($1+90))*degtorad(90-$2))):(radtodeg(degtorad(90-$2)*sin(degtorad($1+90)))):3 notitle
```

where column 1 contains "beta", column 2 is "alpha" but it doesn't matter.

**The question is**

1. how to remove the right ticmarks (`unset y2tics` doesn't work)?
2. how to set "beta=0°" on the upper side (`set x2tics("{/Symbol b}=0{/Symbol \260}" 0)` doesn't work)?

[image: Here is I am now]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unlabelled tics on the right and top border have nothing to do with the x2- and y2-axis. They are the mirrored tics of the x- and y-axis. To switch the right tics off, use `set ytics ... nomirror`.

If I remember correctly, in earlier versions `splot` didn't work at all with x2 and y2 axes. At least with 5.2 you can link the x2 axis to have the same range as the x axis with `set link x2` and then you can place tics on the x2 axis:

```
degtorad(x)=x/180*pi
radtodeg(x)=x/pi*180

set pm3d map
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
set logscale zcb

set palette model RGB rgbformulae 33,13,10

set size ratio 1

set link x2
set x2tics ("{/Symbol b}=180{/Symbol \260}" 0)

set ytics nomirror ("0" -90, "10" -80, "20" -70, "30" -60, "40" -50, "50" -40, "60" -30, "70" -20, "80" -10, "90" 0, "80" 10, "70" 20, "60" 30, "50" 40, "40" 50, "30" 60, "20" 70, "10" 80, "0" 90)

splot[-90:90][-90:90] 'TSC3.txt' u (radtodeg(cos(degtorad($1+90))*degtorad(90-$2))):(radtodeg(degtorad(90-$2)*sin(degtorad($1+90)))):3 notitle
```

Comment: Works as a charm. Thank you very much!